# Why is the "Like" count on my webpage vastly different from the Facebook page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

412 Likes: http://ambianceapp.com
169 Likes: https://www.facebook.com/ambianceapp

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="1230951" />
<meta property="fb:page_id" content="168164236564309" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="156067184497"/>
```

On first glance, I thought that it was combining the `page_id` and `app_id`, but ever since I moved away from the Facebook SDK in my app (one a year ago), the Like count for the [app page](https://www.facebook.com/ambiance) has dwindled to only a handful. Not enough to count towards the 412.

How can I ensure that all 412 people who have liked my site are notified when I post to my Facebook page, and why isn't Facebook showing an accurate count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your website is a different Graph Object, you cannot like a Facebook Fan page via the Like Button on websites. That's why the numbers are different.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, the 169 is all people who have liked my website when shared from other people in their timelines? And anybody that presses like on my actual site is actually liking the old app_id? Where are the 412 showing then?

Comment: They are two separate entities.  I wish facebook would allow us to specify that the like counts should be tied together.

Comment: The 412 people pressed the Like button on your website. The 169 people liked your Facebook Fan Page by going to https://www.facebook.com/ambianceapp and pressing the Like button on Facebook.com. As DMCS already also mentioned, website and Fan page are two different things, they're not connected. There is nothing you can do about it :/

Comment: OK, i understand that they are separate entities, but where did the likes go? Surely the likes on my webpage must go somewhere? Are they linked into the app page but not displayed at https://www.facebook.com/ambiance ?

Comment: Got it all sorted out, sort of. Had to jump through some hoops but I got everything merged finally

Comment: @coneybeare Can you please describe your solution?

Comment: @coneybeare Could you please elaborate on how you managed to merge them? Also, where should I look for likes to my webpage?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the same count on each of them you need to use the same "href" as your facebook page... something like:

```
<fb:like href="http://facebook.com/<page name>" ....></fb:like>
```

That way when they click like it will be as they are clicking like in your facebook page and you will see the same count on both places.

Comment: Does someone validate this answer (other than Agusting)?